# Back button does not navigate to required scene

Tags: lua, coronasdk, back-button

On "tap", firstBar1.lua goes to scene1.lua. If there is no tap during the scene1 timeout then it moves to scene2 and so on; scene1 has a goBack button directed to firstBar1. It goes back for a moment but then continues to scene 2. It needs to stay on firstBar1 until there is another tap. I've tried various button codes and this is the best outcome I have been able to get. print ("firstBar1") doesn't work after tapping the back button.

```
    -- firstBar1.lua
    -----------------------------------------------------

    local composer = require ("composer")            
            print ("firstBar1")
    local scene = composer.newScene()                                       
    function scene:create(event) 
            local screenGroup = self.view

    local widget = require ("widget")

    local function onScene1BtnRelease()
            composer.gotoScene("scene1", "fade", 40)
            return true     
    end

    image1 = "images/staveBlankgrey2.png" 

    local scene1Btn = widget.newButton{
            defaultFile = image1,
            width = 480, height = 320,
            onRelease = onScene1BtnRelease
    } 
        screenGroup:insert(scene1Btn) 

    end

    scene:addEventListener( "create", scene)
    scene:addEventListener( "show", scene)
    scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene)
    scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene)

  return scene
```

Scene1:

```
    -- scene1.lua
    --------------------------------------------------------------------

  local mydata = require ("mydata")

    local composer = require ( "composer")
    local scene = composer.newScene()

            local function showScene2()
                    local options = {
                            effect = "slideLeft",
                            time = 130,
                    }
            composer.gotoScene("scene2", options)
            end

    -- create scene 3

    function scene:createScene ( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    end     

  function scene:show( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    -- will

    if ( phase == "will") then

            data = data + 1
                    if data == 5 then
                    sub = sub + 1
                    data = 1
            end
            if sub == 3 then
            section = section + 1
                    sub = 1
                    data = 1
            end

        stave = display.newImage( "images/staveBlankgrey2.png", 240, 160 )
        note1 = display.newImage( "images/crDown.png", 130, 141 )
        count = display.newImage( workoutTable[section][sub][data], 60, 40 ) 

            sceneGroup:insert( stave )
            sceneGroup:insert( note1 )
            sceneGroup:insert( count )

        -- goBackBtn                                   

            local widget = require ("widget")

            local button = display.newImage("images/goBackBtn.png")
            button.x = display.contentWidth / 2
            button.y = display.contentHeight - 60

            sceneGroup:insert( button )

            function button:tap(event)
                    composer.gotoScene("firstBar1", "fade", 30)
            end
            button:addEventListener("tap", button)
            print ("button 1 pressed")
            sceneGroup:insert( button )
            return true

        -- did

            elseif ( phase == "did") then
                    local function showScene2()
                        local options = {
                             effect = "slideLeft",
                             time = 30,
                                            }
            composer.gotoScene( "scene2", options )
            end

            timer.performWithDelay(tempo, showScene2 )
        end 
end     

    -- hide / destroy

    function scene:hide( event )
            local sceneGroup = self.view
            local phase = event.phase
    end

    function scene:destroy( event )
            local sceneGroup = self.view
    end

    scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
    scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
    scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
    scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

    return scene
```

If I'm missing something out could you also tell me where to include it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you process the back button touch, you need to cancel your timer that's going to the next scene.

At the top of the module declare a variable to store the handle to the timer:

```
local sessionTimer
```

Then when you start the timer do:

```
sessionTimer = timer.performWithDelay(tempo, showScene2 )
```

Finally if you leave the scene prior to the timer's exit, perhaps in your button handler, do:

```
timer.cancel( sessionTimer )
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this but can't find the correct code to achieve it. Please look at 'BackBtn does not cancel timer from previous scene'. Perhaps you can suggest something? Thanks.